# Google Oswald font not displaying correctly when installed on system

Tags: html, css, fonts, woff

So Ive got the Oswald Google font installed and I've noticed that it is not displaying correctly. From another computer that does not have it installed it appears fine. Does anyone know why this is the case? Should this be a concern since probably very few people have this font installed?[image: Oswald getting cut off][image: Also on google font website]

Comment: What systems/browsers are you using? Does anything change if you uninstall the font?

Comment: Viewing in Chrome on Win 7 with font installed, on another PC with Win 7 and Chrome and font not installed looks fine

Comment: Ok, just installed and now its not getting cut off, but the text looks  the same on iPad, Firefox and IE but not on Chrome, the P text seems to be a little bigger, weird, seems like Chrome doesnt like to display its own fonts well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the local font is giving you problems. You can use the [Paul Irish smily hack](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/#smiley) to disable the local font. Disabling it by defining an illegal font name will force the browser to load the web resource.

```
src: local('☺︎'),
```